# check if list object exist and give name them

Tags: r

I am trying to write my own function. And after some calculations for example I am obtaining a list like this ;

[image: obtained list]
And according to data, number of clusters can vary from 1 to 31.

**So, no matter how much the clusters are, I want to list them like the code below.**

```
maxm5<-list(m.5$`Disaggregated rainfall depths`$`Cluster 1`, m.5$`Disaggregated rainfall depths`$`Cluster 2`...)
```

To perform these, I tried `sapply`;

```
maxm5<-sapply(1:31, function(zz) list(m.5$`Disaggregated rainfall depths`$`Cluster [zz]`))
```

And then I tried `for` loop

```
        month<-31 
   maxm5<- for (i in month) {
      list(m.5$`Disaggregated rainfall depths`$`Cluster [i]`)
    }
```

But what I just got is a list with 31 null.

And then I want to give name them like;

```
m5.1<-maxm5[[1]]
m5.2<-maxm5[[2]] ....
```

Comment: `for (i in month)` iterates over the vector `month`, which in this case is only the number 31. You probably want something like `month <- 1:31`

Comment: @camille with `month <- 1:31`, I am getting `maxm5` as 1 line null

Comment: ```m.5$`Disaggregated rainfall depths` ``` returns the list containing all the clusters. Is this not what you want?

Comment: @josemz Actually it is, but I need to find maximums of each cluster. And when I write `max(m.5$`Disaggregated rainfall depths`)` I am getting error. So I tried to find maximums seperately

Comment: Oh my bad, didn't notice the max, how about: ```sapply(m.5$`Disaggregated rainfall depths`, max)```

Comment: @josemz Oh thanks it worked. But there is another trouble. The clusters consist of `year`, `daily`, `season` and `values`. So when the year is 2005, normally as maximum `2005` is found. What can I do to find only `values`' maximum?

Comment: ```sapply(m.5$`Disaggregated rainfall depths`, function(x) max(x$values))```

Comment: @josemz I am so sorry, I explained wrong. https://i.stack.imgur.com/FpcFK.jpg 
This a cluster sample. It has day, season, year, daily and hour_1, hour_2.. and it is going until hour_288. So except day, season, year and daily, I need to find a maximum from rest. It doesn't matter which column or row is.

Comment: We can't replicate this [without a sample of data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your last comment:

```r
sapply(m.5$`Disaggregated rainfall depths`, function(x) max(x[, -(1:4)]))
```